# AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting AllowPromptingForCredentials

Tags: vb.net, remote-desktop

I try to set AllowPromptingForCredentials to False on AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting control (on Windows Vista). But AllowPromptingForCredentials is not available.
My code is :

```
    x = New AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting
    CType(x, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    x.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    x.Enabled = True
    'x.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    x.Name = "OfficeWin7"
    P.Controls.Add(x)
    CType(x, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    x.CreateControl()
    x.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 600)
    x.Server = _server
    x.UserName = _username
    x.AdvancedSettings7.ClearTextPassword = _password
    x.AdvancedSettings5.PublicMode = False
    x.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectDrives = False
    x.AdvancedSettings7.AudioRedirectionMode = 2
    x.AdvancedSettings7.NotifyTSPublicKey = False
    x.FullScreen = False
    x.AdvancedSettings7.SmartSizing = False
    Dim ocx As MSTSCLib.IMsRdpClientNonScriptable4 = x.GetOcx()
    ocx.EnableCredSspSupport = True
    ocx.AllowCredentialSaving = False
    ocx.AllowPromptingForCredentials = False ' here is the problem
    x.AdvancedSettings7.AuthenticationLevel = 0
    x.AdvancedSettings7.GrabFocusOnConnect = True
    x.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectPrinters = False
    x.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectPorts = False
    x.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectSmartCards = False
    x.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectClipboard = False
    x.AdvancedSettings7.EnableAutoReconnect = False
```

Using Visual Studio 2008 (if you must know).
Any idea what am I doing wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is :

```
ocx.PromptForCredentials = False
```

I was not looking in the right direction !

Comment: It is not 100% clear but I believe you may have accomplished what I am trying to do here and I would appreciate your input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669589/prevent-failed-logon-attempt-window-after-failing-to-supply-proper-credentials-t